# How to remove chinese characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

is there any easy way to truncate chinese characters i found that regexp but it doesn't work as expected

```
<?php
$data1='疯狂的管道Test';
$data2='睡眠帮手-背景乐Test';

echo str_replace(preg_replace("/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data1),'',$data1)
."<br>\n".
str_replace(preg_replace("/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data2),'',$data2);
exit;
```

it works for data1 but not data2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code ([online version @ Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/EztSUd)):

```
<?php
$data1='疯狂的管道Test';
$data2='睡眠帮手-背景乐Test';

echo preg_replace("/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data1), "\n";
echo preg_replace("/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data2);

// Better use this (credits to Kobi's answer below)
preg_replace("/\p{Han}+/u", '', $data)
```

I have removed the `^` from the regular expression so we don't need *str_replace()* anymore.

Your old regexp matched all non-chinese characters thus `preg_replace()` only left chinese character in the returned string. In order to obtain the final result, you had to replace the found chinese characters by an empty string.

```
preg_replace("/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data1) // returns 疯狂的管道
str_replace('疯狂的管道', '', $data1); // gives us Test
```

The second regexp again matched all non-chinese characters. But now, they are **not** in a sequence!

```
preg_replace("/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u", '', $data2) // returns 睡眠帮手背景乐
```

And this string cannot be found in `$data2` anymore thus it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a [Unicode character property](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) ([Han](http://www.unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html) should work for you):

```
preg_replace("/\p{Han}+/u", '', $data)
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/uEiIV5

Comment: Elegant solution

Comment: Some reading about http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn26/

Answer (score 0):

This one should also do the job
`/[^\u4E00-\u9FFF]+/`

Comment: The regular expression is not the actual problem. The problem is that the match of the second regexp doesn't represent a sequence in the original string which could be replaced.

Comment: By "doesn't" match - do you mean the '-' in the second var?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If **all** chinese characters in the second regexp would be consecutive, it would work.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it: http://ideone.com/jwa9Gp Nevertheless your regexp doesn't address the actual problem (if I just replace the OP's regexp with yours).