# PHP allow all accented characters in person name, but don't allow Chinese/Russian characters

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-match

I am having issues with allowing all English/Latin based characters (including accents), but disallowing Chinese/Russian characters.

The first version I had was as follows:

```
strlen($values['person_name']) != mb_strlen($values['person_name'], 'utf-8')
```

This one worked fine initially, but when Icelandic/Czech names came into play, this did not work anymore.

The second version I had was as follows:

```
preg_match("~^[a-zÀ-ÿ][\'a-zÀ-ÿ \-]*$~i", $values['person_name'])
```

This seemed to work fine for majority of cases, but it is giving an error on a test name

> **Eliška Koňaříková**

I have tried the following as well without any luck:

```
preg_match("/[^\w ]/u", $values['person_name'])      //does not allow š
preg_match("/\PL/u", $values['person_name'])      //does not allow š
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'\-\pL]+$/u", $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
preg_match("/^[\s,.'-]*\p{L}[\p{L}\s,.'-]*$/u", $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9àâáçéèèêëìîíïôòóùûüÂÊÎÔúÛÄËÏÖÜÀÆæÇÉÈŒœÙñý,. ]/u", $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
preg_match("~^[a-zÀ-ÿ][\'a-zÀ-ÿ \-]*$~iu", $values['person_name'])      //does not allow š
preg_match("/^[\p{L}-]*$/u", $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
preg_match("/([\w ]{2,})/u", $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
preg_match('/[^\p{Latin}0-9€, !"§$%&\/()=#|<>]/u', $values['person_name'])      //allows š, but also allows 書
```

All of the above either failed with the name provided, or it allowed Chinese characters.

I believe the best route for me would be to revert back to the check that was working for most characters (except with the Czech names that are giving an error):

```
preg_match("~^[a-zÀ-ÿ][\'a-zÀ-ÿ \-]*$~i", $values['person_name'])
```

And manually add the Czech characters that are not accepted such as š, ň, ř, etc.

Is there a cleaner solution than manually having to specify each of these characters?

Comment: OUt of interested, why do you want to exclude these characters? Trying to think of why that would be useful

Comment: You could check every char for a transliteration. If not exists, remove.

Comment: Unicode ranges might be the best way. Here's Cyrillic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026487/231316, and here's Chinese (although read the comments on the various answers): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17927160/231316

Comment: @ADyson, The competition is a global event, but when entering for the finals of the event, the student info is carried over to the finals, where all Schedules/Certificates/Reports should be in English characters for the announcer to be able to read. Instead of having to change student names between events.

This is a rule that is enforced by the Event Head Office.

Comment: So Arabic, Japanese, Korean, Greek, Hindi, Hebrew, Thai and several others are still viable? Or maybe they just aren't in this competition. I just ask because it might be better to constrain to what is supported, instead of trying to remove what isn't.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I only require characters with English/Latin root characters.  All other non-English/Latin characters should give the user an error. Languages such as Czech, Icelandic, Croatian, etc. should be accepted, so if a letter is in any form of an "s" for example, it should be allowed, but Chinese, Russian, Arabic, Japanese, Korean, Greek, Hindi, Hebrew, etc should not be. There may be some characters in the alphabet that resemble their English counterpart, and they could possibly be allowed, but those that are obviously not English characters should not. Hope this makes sense

Comment: MarkusZeller & ChrisHaas, Thanks for letting me know about Transliterations, I used iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $values['person_name']) to convert the name and then check for A-Z letters and this seems to be working correctly, will do some further test to see if there are any letters that are giving a false positive/negative

Comment: Do you want to disallow Russian/Chinese letters (as in title) or Icelandic/Czech (as in the question itself)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it should disallow Russian/Chinese or any other non-English/Latin based characters, while allowing Icelandic/Czech and other characters that still base characters like English. In other words it should allow ALL variations of the letter D (đ, Ď) and R (Ř, ȓ), but not characters like ж, ф, 汉

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match()` allows to use unicode scripts:

- Latin script: `\p{Latin}`
- At least one char: `\p{Latin}+`
- Anchor to string start/end: `^\p{Latin}+$`
- Pattern delimiters: `(^\p{Latin}+$)`
- Disallow linefeed at string end: `(^\p{Latin}+$)D`
- Unicode (UTF-8) mode: `(^\p{Latin}+$)Du`

```php
$values = ['English', 'አማርኛ', 'Anarâškielâ', 'अंगिका', 'Аԥсшәа', 'Aragonés', 'অসমীয়া'];

foreach ($values as $value) {
  $matched = preg_match('(^\\p{Latin}+$)Du', $value);
  echo $value, ' ', ($matched ? '✔️' : '❌'), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
English ✔️
አማርኛ ❌
Anarâškielâ ✔️
अंगिका ❌
Аԥсшәа ❌
Aragonés ✔️
অসমীয়া ❌
```

For transliteration check the `Transliterator` class. It is parts of PHPs standard unicode extension - `ext/intl`. It allows for extensive transformations of unicode strings.

```php
$transliterator = \Transliterator::create('Any-Latin'); 
var_dump($transliterator->transliterate('አማርኛ Anarâškielâ अंगिका Аԥсшәа Aragonés অসমীয়া'));
$transliterator = \Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII'); 
var_dump($transliterator->transliterate('አማርኛ Anarâškielâ अंगिका Аԥсшәа Aragonés অসমীয়া'));
```

Output:

```
string(69) "አማርኛ Anarâškielâ aṅgikā Aԥsšəa Aragonés asamīẏā"
string(57) "አማርኛ Anaraskiela angika Aԥssəa Aragones asamiya"
```

The first (untransformed) word in the example is Amharisch. Even ICU has limits depending on the version.

More about the ICU Script Transliterations: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/#scriptlanguage

Comment: Thank you very much for proving the breakdown of the preg_match, I will test this with a bunch of different characters to make see if there are any false positives or negatives, but based on the example provided it will do exactly what I require

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [script run](https://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2unicode.html) unicode property:

```
$pattern = '~
  \A
    (?=\p{Latin}) 
    (*asr: [\pL\pM ]+)
  \z
~xu';

$tests = [
    'Das Wohltemperierte Klavier',
    'Добре темперирано пиано',
    'Le Clavier bien tempére'."\xcc\x81", // <-- combining acute
    'Il clavicembalo ben temperato',
    '平均律クラヴィーア曲集',
    'El clavecí ben temprat',
    'เดอะเวลล์-เทมเพิร์ดคลาเวียร์',
    'Eliška Koňaříková',
    'Eliška Koňaříková 1 2 3',
    
];

print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $tests));
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/fQIbt#v8.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's better to replace the chars, this is only an example of doing that and it's not a complete function:

```
<?php
replace($str, $options = array())
    {

        // Make sure string is in UTF-8 and strip invalid UTF-8 characters
        $str = mb_convert_encoding((string)$str, 'UTF-8', mb_list_encodings());

        $defaults = array(
            'delimiter' => '',
            'limit' => null,
            'lowercase' => true,
            'replacements' => array(),
            'transliterate' => false,
        );

        // Merge options
        $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);

        $char_map = array(
            // Latin
            'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'Ç' => 'C',
            'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I',
            'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O',
            'Ø' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Þ' => 'TH',
            'ß' => 'ss',
            'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c',
            'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i',
            'ð' => 'd', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o',
            'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'th',
            'ÿ' => 'y',
            // Latin symbols
            '©' => '(c)',
            // Greek
            'Α' => 'A', 'Β' => 'B', 'Γ' => 'G', 'Δ' => 'D', 'Ε' => 'E', 'Ζ' => 'Z', 'Η' => 'H', 'Θ' => '8',
            'Ι' => 'I', 'Κ' => 'K', 'Λ' => 'L', 'Μ' => 'M', 'Ν' => 'N', 'Ξ' => '3', 'Ο' => 'O', 'Π' => 'P',
            'Ρ' => 'R', 'Σ' => 'S', 'Τ' => 'T', 'Υ' => 'Y', 'Φ' => 'F', 'Χ' => 'X', 'Ψ' => 'PS', 'Ω' => 'W',
            'Ά' => 'A', 'Έ' => 'E', 'Ί' => 'I', 'Ό' => 'O', 'Ύ' => 'Y', 'Ή' => 'H', 'Ώ' => 'W', 'Ϊ' => 'I',
            'Ϋ' => 'Y',
            'α' => 'a', 'β' => 'b', 'γ' => 'g', 'δ' => 'd', 'ε' => 'e', 'ζ' => 'z', 'η' => 'h', 'θ' => '8',
            'ι' => 'i', 'κ' => 'k', 'λ' => 'l', 'μ' => 'm', 'ν' => 'n', 'ξ' => '3', 'ο' => 'o', 'π' => 'p',
            'ρ' => 'r', 'σ' => 's', 'τ' => 't', 'υ' => 'y', 'φ' => 'f', 'χ' => 'x', 'ψ' => 'ps', 'ω' => 'w',
            'ά' => 'a', 'έ' => 'e', 'ί' => 'i', 'ό' => 'o', 'ύ' => 'y', 'ή' => 'h', 'ώ' => 'w', 'ς' => 's',
            'ϊ' => 'i', 'ΰ' => 'y', 'ϋ' => 'y', 'ΐ' => 'i',
            // Turkish
            'Ş' => 'S', 'İ' => 'I', 'Ç' => 'C', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ğ' => 'G',
            'ş' => 's', 'ı' => 'i', 'ç' => 'c', 'ü' => 'u', 'ö' => 'o', 'ğ' => 'g',
            // Russian
            'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'Yo', 'Ж' => 'Zh',
            'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
            'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
            'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sh', 'Ъ' => '', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu',
            'Я' => 'Ya',
            'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'ж' => 'zh',
            'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o',
            'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
            'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sh', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu',
            'я' => 'ya',
            // Ukrainian
            'Є' => 'Ye', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'Yi', 'Ґ' => 'G',
            'є' => 'ye', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'ґ' => 'g',
            // Czech
            'Č' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ň' => 'N', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Š' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ů' => 'U',
            'Ž' => 'Z',
            'č' => 'c', 'ď' => 'd', 'ě' => 'e', 'ň' => 'n', 'ř' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ť' => 't', 'ů' => 'u',
            'ž' => 'z',
            // Polish
            'Ą' => 'A', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Ę' => 'e', 'Ł' => 'L', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ó' => 'o', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Ź' => 'Z',
            'Ż' => 'Z',
            'ą' => 'a', 'ć' => 'c', 'ę' => 'e', 'ł' => 'l', 'ń' => 'n', 'ó' => 'o', 'ś' => 's', 'ź' => 'z',
            'ż' => 'z',
            // Latvian
            'Ā' => 'A', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ē' => 'E', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ī' => 'i', 'Ķ' => 'k', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'Ņ' => 'N',
            'Š' => 'S', 'Ū' => 'u', 'Ž' => 'Z',
            'ā' => 'a', 'č' => 'c', 'ē' => 'e', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ī' => 'i', 'ķ' => 'k', 'ļ' => 'l', 'ņ' => 'n',
            'š' => 's', 'ū' => 'u', 'ž' => 'z'
        );

        // Make custom replacements
        $str = preg_replace(array_keys($options['replacements']), $options['replacements'], $str);

        // Transliterate characters to ASCII
        if ($options['transliterate']) {
            $str = str_replace(array_keys($char_map), $char_map, $str);
        }

        // Replace non-alphanumeric characters with our delimiter
        $str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+/u', $options['delimiter'], $str);

        // Remove duplicate delimiters
        $str = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($options['delimiter'], '/') . '){2,}/', '$1', $str);

        // Truncate slug to max. characters
        $str = mb_substr($str, 0, ($options['limit'] ? $options['limit'] : mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')), 'UTF-8');

        // Remove delimiter from ends
        $str = trim($str, $options['delimiter']);

        return $options['lowercase'] ? mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8') : $str;
    }
```